# server bandwidth

Tags: linux, bandwidth

I have a 2 mbps connection ( 240 KB/s download ), when I download a file from my server I get only 40 KB/s. The iftop output shows me the total bandwidth of around 20 mbps( receiving and transmitting bandwidth are equally split ) which is distributed among a large number of users which explains why I am getting such low download speeds. However, when I wget in another window the bandwidth increases to around 40 mbps( Receiving ~ 30 mbps and transmitting ~ 10mbps). If the network is capable of giving 40 mbps why are my users not getting it?

update: my users are also downloading files from the server through the internet. By connection speed i'm referring to speed my users get while downloading. If i'm not getting 240 Kb/s that means even my users won't be getting their maximum possible speed.

Answer (score 1):

Internet links are often *asymmetrical* and *full duplex*.

Asymmetrical means that the possible upload and download speeds are different. Full duplex means that you can send traffic in one direction without affecting traffic in the other direction (unless you start dropping ACK packets due to saturation).

So it doesn't make sense to just add up the upload and download speeds to get a "total bandwidth" number. You should consider them separately.

In your case, I would guess that your server has a max upload bandwidth of 10Mbps and a max download bandwidth of 30Mbps.

Answer (score 0):

We will need more information to properly answer your question. How are your users and your server connected? Wireless? Wired? Switches? When you say bandwidth is slow are you saying between the users and the Internet or the users and your server?